# Ankh Svn Client Side Hook

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, svn-hooks

My question is simple; I wish to use tortoisesvn-esque client-side hooks in Ankh svn, how do I go about this?

I've toggled the "Enable Client side hooks" in Tools->Options:Source control->Subversion
in my visual studio 2010 environment, but I have no idea where to store the hook-scripts.

It does not connect to the ones in my tortoise svn folder, and copying them to c:\Program\AnkhSVN 2\hooks doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your using TortoiseSVN's [*Cient Side* hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)?

They aren't stored in the folders and are what AnkSVN uses...